# Httpwatch automation for chrome

Tags: performance-testing, pageload, page-load-time, httpwatch

I have automated IE using httpwatch. but can't do the same with chrome.
whether we can do it or not in httpwatch?

if yes!
Can you guys let me know how to automate **chrome** using **httpwatch**?

if not! 
Then which will be the best tool to automate chrome and IE for pageload time(free tool) ?

my web app is built using angular js.

Please help me out guys.

Comment: What programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome support was added in HttpWatch 11.0 but automation was not be available until HttpWatch 11.1 was released. There're more information about the Chrome support in this blog post:

https://blog.httpwatch.com/2017/06/06/new-httpwatch-11-x-supports-chrome/

And these blog posts cover the automation of HttpWatch in Chrome:

https://blog.httpwatch.com/2017/12/12/automated-page-load-testing-with-chrome-and-httpwatch-1-1/

https://blog.httpwatch.com/2018/01/11/how-to-use-selenium-automation-with-httpwatch-and-chrome/

Comment: I am hoping it gets released soon

Comment: guys do u know how to find the page load time in httpwatch when a new browser, which opens up upon clicking an button in existing browser?

Comment: Have you tried enabling auto-recording? If you open HttpWatch in the new window or tab you can see the page load time